# read contents of CSV file received as base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm trying to read the csv file received as base64 string as below

```
csvBase64Content = "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"

decrypted = b64.b64decode(csvBase64Content)
with open(decrypted) as csvFile:
   #other stuff
```

Getting error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open a bunch of bytes. Just loop over what you have (as below) or use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

```
import base64 as b64

csvBase64Content = "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"

csv = b64.b64decode(csvBase64Content).decode('utf-8').split(',')
for v in csv:
    print(v)
```

Comment: This will break if you have a complicated CSV. Best to use the `csv` module

Comment: He can use any module he wants. The point was that he was trying to open bytes and now he isn't.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer that works with your data - note I needed the `.decode('utf-8')` method for it to run.

```
import base64
import csv
import io

csvBase64Content = "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"

decrypted = base64.b64decode(csvBase64Content).decode('utf-8')
with io.StringIO(decrypted) as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Hi Ben, This code is throwing error to me. I'm using python 3.7.  reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reader'

Comment: @ShaikhMudassir , do you have a variable that's a `list` named `csv`? If so, it's conflicting with the `import csv` statement

Comment: Try copying this code into a new file and running it. Does that work?

Comment: This method of opening the file worked for me to use the `csv.Sniffer` to find the delimiter.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with python3 and getting the error:
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: @Prashant - It's using universal newlines by default (`newline=None`). You can try `newline=''` with the following code: `with io.StringIO(decrypted, newline='') as fp:` - see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make use of the `csv` module to understand the "file" contents, you can create a file-like object from the decrypted bytes:

```
import csv, io

data = b64.b64decode(...)
reader = csv.Reader(io.StringIO(data))
# use `reader`'s methods
```